# Check if the number $3^{2015} - 2^{2015}$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factoring

Is $3^{2015} - 2^{2015}$ a prime. If not, why?

Comment: We'll I stupidly thought you could ignore the indices due to them being equal

Comment: Well all I am seeing is a homework dump with a very unhelpful heading

Comment: Well if you could point me in correct direction I would be happy

Comment: It is not about *your* happiness - I figured the answer, but as with my students - you show an effort *first*, then I help

Comment: Why do you need the help to be desperate?

Comment: LOL okay I shall go elsewhere

Comment: Is it homework that you left to the last minute or is it a code that will diffuse a bucket of banana puree hovering above your head?

Comment: The later LOOL, it's a question I came across while studying maths with a bud. Thought it was straight forward but no

Comment: I was sort of fond of the original title.

Comment: I tried to use a calculator with logs etc. but I am baffled

Comment: It is easier (imo) to prove composite numbers are composite than to prove primes are prime.  The reason is that you can just give a factorization.  Can you find any good factorization of this number?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** If $a \mid b$ then $x^a - y^a \mid x^b - y^b$.

Comment: Thank you Very much. I appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

HINT: use $$a^5-b^5=(a-b) \left(a^4+a^3 b+a^2 b^2+a b^3+b^4\right)$$
with $a=3^{403}$ and $b=2^{403}$

Comment: Thank you very much, I feel humbled

Comment: If applied to above Wouldn't that make the a very long equation. How will it prove if it's a prime or not?

Comment: $a-b$ is not a prime

Comment: my PC takes over two weeks to solve this